# Docker link container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im am using docker compose to run 2 containers (both centos based). This is my yml:

```
front:
  build: front/docker/java
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  links:
    - back:db
back:
  build: back/docker/java
  ports:
    - "8081:8081"
```

But the `front` container gets nothing in the `/etc/hosts` for or `env` vars to be able to connect to the `back` container. I am running docker 1.3.2.

Comment: AFAIK docker won't touch `/etc/hosts` in the container. You should be getting a handful of environment variables like `DB_PORT`, `DB_PORT_8081_TCP`, etc as described [in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env/). My guess is you might not be checking for the correct environment variable names or you might not be accessing environment variables correctly in your program. Could you post exactly how you are determining that you "get nothing"?

Comment: @PeterLyons yea turns out it was because i was using `run` instead of `exec` to list the env vars

Comment: There should be an update to /etc/hosts in front.  Did you verify a entry for 'db' while exec'ed into front?  In my local testing, I see 3 host updates for each link (compose invents some dns names).  You also get the environment variables which are handy to programmatically wait for the other container's service to come online